# How can I retrieve transaction hashes using web3 batch requests?

Tags: web3js, truffle, ethereumjs, truffle-contract

When I send a transaction using Truffle's contract wrappers - or using plain web3 sendTransaction() - I get a tx hash back that I can use to confirm the tx has completed. While using batch requests (https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#batch-requests), I'm unable to find a way to get the tx hash of any of the requests in the batch. Is there a way? It doesn't look like batch.execute() returns anything or supports any callbacks - so I'm a bit stuck.

I'm using batch requests to make sure my transactions get sent in a fixed order.

Thanks!

Comment: Transactions from the same account are always serialized because the nonces have to be consecutive numbers. I've only used batch previously with calls, so I didn't expect hashes in return.

Comment: I saw cases where I'd call async functions (without await) in one order and the transactions would get sent in a different order. I'm using truffle contract wrappers to promisify sendTransaction(). I'll try await before the calls to make sure they run in the order I'm specifying. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have the same issue, how did you handle it?

Comment: I didn't find a way to get any tx hashes using batch requests. But as @Ismael says above, the txs do get sent in the expected order after all.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `web3.batchRequest()` to create and execute batch requests (after waiting for a transaction receipt) and you will get the transaction hash as a return value from the callback provided by the request object.

```
// create batch object
let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
let batch = new web3.BatchRequest();

// add and execute batch requests 
const batchExecution = () => {
    try {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            batch.add(contract.methods.SomeFunc2(params).call.request(...), callback));
            batch.add(contract.methods.SomeFunc2(params)
            .call.request({from: address}, (err,tx) => {
                    waitForReceipt(tx, (reciept) => {
                            console.log(":::::::::::::::::waitForReceipt::::::::", tx);
                    console.log(":::::::::::::::::receipt::::::::", receipt);
                    const data = { success: receipt?.status };
                   resolve(data); };
            });
            batch.execute(); // execute batch request after receipt is generated
        });
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("error");
    }
}

// generate transaction receipt
const waitForReceipt = (tx, cb) => {
    let receipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReciept(tx, function(err, receipt) {
        if(receipt){
            cb(receipt);
        } else {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
            waitForReceipt(tx, cb); 
          }, 2000);
        }
    });
}
```

See: https://aniruddha-deshmukh.hashnode.dev/how-to-send-batch-transactions-on-ethereum-using-web3js

Answer (score 1):

Every call you add to the batch, requires you to use a callback after sending the parameters.

For example:

batch.add(web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash, (err,res) => {console.log(res)}))

batch.execute():

So now you will print every result that you get from the batch.

Comment: You are missing the request part. It should be something like `batch.add(web3.eth.getTransaction.request(txHash, (err,res) => {console.log(res)}))`.